# Questions migrated correctly?

Tags: discussion, migration

I saw this particular situation once before but wanted to question it today.  [This](https://superuser.com/questions/563361/how-to-inform-ubuntu-12-04-apt-get-about-older-installed-version-of-php) question was migrated from Stack Overflow to Super User, but it would serve better value at Ask Ubuntu.

When I commented on this my comment was deleted. So how does one decide where a question should be migrated to? Why when a question is flagged to recommend a move to a better location it doesn't list all the choices? I was under the impression that content should be migrated to the best site and also limit an overwhelming amount to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Five users (or at least 4 I think) migrated the question to Super User.

> migrated to superuser.com by martin clayton, Björn Kaiser, Linuxios, spajce, Tom Mar 9 at 16:30

The "problem" there is that Ask Ubuntu is not a migration target regular users can select on SO. Super User is. If it is an appropriate question there, there really is no problem.

Comment: So what benefit are we serving to AskUbuntu?  Many talented people here in certain areas would be able to offer better answers on the topic it is targeted to.

Comment: @graphicsman It is primarily up to the OP to select the appropriate site. The number of migration targets is limited because, frankly, we suck at selecting appropriate migration targets. Mostly because we often don't know the target site as well as we do SO. If you see a question next time which doesn't belong on SO, but would be a good fit for a site that's not on the list of targets, perhaps flag it for moderator attention. But once again, it's really up to the OP to select the right site from the start. We have done the OP a service in this case, even if it might not be the best site.